# I want to create an Excel like pivot using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my database:

```
| ID    | Repeat_Times |
| ------| -------------|
| 99    | 3            |
| 100   | 4            |
| 99    | 5            |
```

---

The results I need:

| ID | Repeat_Times |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | 8 |
| 100 | 4 |

I'd just take a pivot in Excel, what should I use in SQL?

Comment: What database do you use ? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL ?

Comment: @VBoka SQL Server

Comment: Please, describe what is your attempt and what is wrong with it.

Comment: @astentx I want to replicate making a pivot in Excel in SQL Server. I am unable to correctly use the PIVOT query

Comment: You do not need pivot, if your read the documentation about it. It is simple aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the table name is "repeat_table", so in general you can do the query as below to get that expected result

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Repeat_Times) AS Repeat_Times FROM repeat_table GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I applied this query and it gave me this error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator. So i looked up the error and applied this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673346/16023426

Comment: Is this okay? can you please explain what was the issue?

Comment: @Divya, I am sure that you can find out yourself what is wrong with aplaying this method if you try to check the description error "Operand data type varchar is invalid" here on StackOverflow

Comment: @VBoka yes sure! Thank you